# Angular http request time in interceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http-interceptors, google-chrome-console

I'm making an interceptor to log my http requests.

So far, so good, everything is working as expected.

What I want now is to get the time the request took to be executed.

I thought I could do something like this

```
const start = Date.now();
return next
  .handle(req)
  .map(res => {
    console.log('took ' + (Date.now() - start) + 'ms');
    return res;
  })
```

}

But the console shows 1 to 2ms, while the network shows more than 50ms ... I think that I should create the start value right when I create the request, but I don't know how.

Any solution ?

**PS** : my linting config forbids me to use `console.time()`

Answer (score 6):

use `performance.now()` to measure time duration in milliseconds

```
var start = performance.now(); 

return next
  .handle(req)
  .map(res => {
    console.log('took ' + (performance.now() - start) + 'ms');
    return res;
  })
```

For futher info check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you, but it's even worse :D I just made an edit saying I should instantiate the start value right when I create the request, but since Angular is abstracting all of the process, I don't know how. Anyways, +1 for teaching me something !

Comment: Did you ever resolve this time discrepancy? I am running into a similar issue, but I am seeing 300ms in the browser's network tab and 17,000ms in my logs.