# How to get the page load time including api calls after routing to a new url in Angular 15?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular15

I was trying to get the page load time in my code after all the API calls returned a response, and all the scripts, images etc have been downloaded.

[Image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3LXn.png)

I want the time circled in red in my code, or at the very least, be able to call a function when that time has passed in my typescript.

So far, I have tried two methods windows.addEventListener('load') event listener, and that only gave me the time it took to render the page (and isn't called when I use a router to go to different pages), but not the api calls, and the other method is to manually call a function to keep track of API calls on each component which seems too much of a manual work imo, and therefore a last resort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular http request time in interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115677/angular-http-request-time-in-interceptor)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best solution but you could use an Angular Interceptor and count how many calls were sent vs completed https://angular.io/guide/http-intercept-requests-and-responses

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.